# Не запускается Kali Linux с внешнего жёсткого диска

Tags: linux, hdd, внешние-устройства

Установил Kali на внешний жёсткий диск. В Boot Menu нет пункта по типу USB или HDD. Решил поставить первым по списку в Bios в Boot order USB bevies. Но всё равно загружает винду. Что делать?

Извиняюсь если вопрос может показаться глупым.

Comment: Материнка какой фирмы?

Comment: Не могу сказать. А это имеет значение?

Comment: У разных материнок - разные хоткеи для квик бут меню.

Comment: Абажди. Не можешь сказать? В смысле? У тебя нет доступа к корпусу? У тебя нет dmidecode? Что мешает сказать фирму? Может лучше подтянуть базу, а Kali оставить до лучших времён?

Comment: Мне знать это было не очень нужно, а доступ получить не могу у меня ноутбук. Вопрос уже закрыт. Спасибо.

Comment: @Somik как по итогу поступили?

Comment: Отчистил диск и всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего - проблема в отсутствии загрузчика на съемном диске.
Менее вероятно - что-то с разметкой диска.

Для того, чтобы загрузчик точно установился на съемный диск можно сделать так:

- на машине, с которой происходит установка ОС в биосе отключите все установленные жесткие диски
- подключите внешний диск и произведите чистую установку kali
- по завершении работ не забудьте подключить жесткие диски в биос

Comment: А в данные на основном жёстком диске сохранятся? И надо будет производить отключение каждый раз?

Comment: @Somik При извлечении флэшки из устройства данные сохраняются? Вот жесткий диск у вас - та же флэшка, так что данные никуда не денутся. Отключать диски каждый раз не нужно. Как бы это даже не обязательно делать - просто такой костыль, который должен вам помочь и не заставит углубляться в тонкости установки и настройки ОС. Объясню свою логику - если в процессе установки операционки у вас не будет подключено других дисков - значит вы не промахнетесь диском при создании загрузчика и он точно будет записан на нужное вам устройство.

Comment: Благодарю вас, но у мегя не получается произвести отключение дисков. Я смотрел статьи и не одна не подходит. У меня просто нет такого пункта. Может быть есть другой способ?

Comment: @Somik можно физически отключить диск) Но тогда уж лучше все-таки внимательно подойти к установке ОС и вручную выбрать нужный вам диск для загрузчика.

Comment: Пожалуй к таким метадам прибегать не буду. Тогда можно ли удалить всё с диска? Именно с внешнего. Просто он не отображается в проводнике.

Comment: @Somik можно удалить через управление дисками (ПКМ на Пуск -> управление дисками)